# Yii Ajax error 500

Tags: yii, frameworks

I did a master detail with a Clistview that generate a Cgridview but when i click in the link what call the function crash and say:

```
Error 500: <h1>PHP Error [8]</h1>
<p>Undefined offset: 0 (C:\APP\htdocs\yii\yiitest\protected\controllers\ZfInmueblesController.php:176)</p>
```

I thought it was ajax but I have a filter form without ajax and pagination also said same error.

CONTROLLER:

```
$dataProviderDoc = new CActiveDataProvider(ZfDocumentacionInmueble::model(), array(
            'keyAttribute'=>'doc_id',
            'criteria'=>array(
                'condition'=>'zf_inmuebles_inmueble_id=-1',
            ),
        ));

        if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest){
            // el update del CGridView Productos hecho en Ajax produce un ajaxRequest sobre el mismo
            // action que lo invoco por primera vez y el argumento fue pasado mediante {data: xxx} al // momento de hacer el update al CGridView con id 'productos'
            $zf_inmuebles_inmueble_id = $_GET[0];
            // actualizas el criteria del data provider para ajustarlo a lo que se pide:
            $dataProviderDoc->criteria = array('condition'=>'zf_inmuebles_inmueble_id='.$zf_inmuebles_inmueble_id);
            // para responderle al request ajax debes hacer un ECHO con el JSON del dataprovider
            echo CJSON::encode($dataProviderDoc);
        }
```

VIEW (index):

```
function mostrarDetalles($id){
        // no olvides configurar tu CActiveDataProvider con: 'keyAttribute'=>'idcategoria',
        alert($id);
        //var doc_id = $.fn.yiiListView.getSelection('inmuebles');
        var id_inm = $id;
        $.fn.yiiGridView.update('docs',{ data: id_inm });
    }
```

VIEW (_view):

```
echo CHtml::link('DOCUMENTACIÓN '.$img, '#documentacion', array('data-toggle' => 'modal','onclick'=>"{mostrarDetalles($id)}",));
```

ERROR GET:

```
PHP Error [8]

Undefined offset: 0 (C:\APP\htdocs\yii\yiitest\protected\controllers\ZfInmueblesController.php:177)

#0 C:\APP\htdocs\yii\yiitest\protected\controllers\ZfInmueblesController.php(177): CWebApplication->handleError()#1 C:\APP\htdocs\yii\framework\web\actions\CInlineAction.php(49): ZfInmueblesController->actionIndex()#2 C:\APP\htdocs\yii\framework\web\CController.php(308): CInlineAction->runWithParams()#3 C:\APP\htdocs\yii\framework\web\filters\CFilterChain.php(133): ZfInmueblesController->runAction()#4 C:\APP\htdocs\yii\yiitest\protected\modules\cruge\components\CrugeAccessControlFilter.php(90): CFilterChain->run()#5 C:\APP\htdocs\yii\framework\web\filters\CFilter.php(38): CrugeAccessControlFilter->preFilter()#6 C:\APP\htdocs\yii\framework\web\filters\CFilterChain.php(130): CrugeAccessControlFilter->filter()#7 C:\APP\htdocs\yii\framework\web\filters\CFilter.php(40): CFilterChain->run()#8 C:\APP\htdocs\yii\framework\web\CController.php(1145): CAccessControlFilter->filter()#9 C:\APP\htdocs\yii\framework\web\filters\CInlineFilter.php(58): ZfInmueblesController->filterAccessControl()#10 C:\APP\htdocs\yii\framework\web\filters\CFilterChain.php(130): CInlineFilter->filter()#11 C:\APP\htdocs\yii\framework\web\CController.php(291): CFilterChain->run()#12 C:\APP\htdocs\yii\framework\web\CController.php(265): ZfInmueblesController->runActionWithFilters()#13 C:\APP\htdocs\yii\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(282): ZfInmueblesController->run()#14 C:\APP\htdocs\yii\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(141): CWebApplication->runController()#15 C:\APP\htdocs\yii\framework\base\CApplication.php(180): CWebApplication->processRequest()#16 C:\APP\htdocs\yii\yiitest\index.php(13): CWebApplication->run()
```

Comment: please post your controller

Comment: please check $_GET[0] whether it contains value on key "0". write CVarDumper::Dump($_GET[0],100); die(); i hope it will return null

Comment: Where can I write that?

Comment: before the line at which you are getting error, the line $zf_inmuebles_inmueble_id = $_GET['id_inm'];, before this line write that statement

Comment: ok, sorry for being a noob, how can I echo the value?

Comment: use inspect element of your browser, in the bottom you will see tabs, one of them will be Network. click that. Now initiate your ajax call, the request could be seen here. Now under response you can find the returned value from controller action

Comment: see edit please, ERROR GET

Comment: please mention in your controller which line is numered 177?

Comment: $error = CVarDumper::Dump($_GET[0],100);

Comment: Thats what i am trying to say that please put CVarDumper::Dump($_GET);die();  before line 177

Comment: Sorry, the line 177 is $error = CVarDumper::Dump($_GET[0],100); now

Comment: please dont use [0] just write $_GET

Comment: Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK

Comment: Now please check the response tab in the upper row and post that result

Comment: array
(
    'ajax' => 'docs'
)

Comment: ok, it seems that when you call mostrarDetalles($id), then $id is null. So when you write var id_inm = $id; then id_inm is also null thats y it is not being sent through ajax request

Comment: But when I alert the $id; alert($id); It print the right value :S

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47985/discussion-between-rafay-zia-mir-and-sergio-hw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `$GET[0]`. In your given code index 0 is not defined thats y it gives error. Array always consists of `key=>value pair`.

```
array(
    key  => value,
    key2 => value2,
    key3 => value3,
    ...
)
```

In your code `$.fn.yiiGridView.update`. Actually this code automatically send ajax request to controller.
As you are sending data as `{data: id_inm }` So you need to access this as `$_GET['id_inm']`.

```
$zf_inmuebles_inmueble_id = $_GET['id_inm'];
```

Add

```
CVarDumper::Dump($_GET,100,true);
die();
```

before line 177 at which you are getting error

Comment: Same error with $zf_inmuebles_inmueble_id = $_GET['id_inm'];

Comment: then before this line write CVarDumper::Dump($_GET,100,true);die(); it will show you the key,value pairs in $_GET array, and please post the result

Comment: I did it: $.fn.yiiGridView.update('docs',{ data: 'id_inm='+id_inm });

Comment: good, try to master debugging because many things can be solved by debugging, you just need to know how to debug.

Answer (score 1):

if there is a variable in your function, set it like,

```
public function actionName($_GET[0] = 0){
    echo $_GET[0];
}
```

Comment: now It doesn't send the error, but it's not working, don't filter the dataProvider

Comment: ok, but if $_GET[0] = 1; It's filtering with the id 1, so the problem is that in the request the variable is not taken the value from get